# Django ORM bulk_update

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have stuck on this task.
I have Professor model and i need to update from 2 queries but i have 6 queries in my DB.

```
from django.db import models

class Professor(models.Model):
   first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
   age = models.IntegerField(default=18)
```

My function.

```
def update_professor_first_names():
    first_name_updates = [(1, 'freddie'), (2, 'mady'), (3, 'hady'), (4, 'michael'), (5, 'rose')]
    tmp = []
    for prof_id, new_first_name in first_name_updates:
        prof = Professor.objects.get(id=prof_id)
        prof.first_name = new_first_name
        tmp.append(prof)
    Professor.objects.bulk_update(tmp, ['first_name'])
```

Please give me some advices.

Comment: what do you mean "*i have 6 queries*" ?

Comment: 6 request in my DB

Comment: this topic have solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71616089/queryset-object-has-no-attribute-pk-in-bulk-update/71616317#71616317

Answer (score 1):

right now you're running a `get` on every ID which generates 5 queries, then one for the update, which totals 6 queries.

you can use the `__in` operator with all of the IDs to run one query getting the professors you want to update, then run the bulk update after you've assigned the names, for two queries total:

```
id_set = [id for id, first_name in first_name_updates]
profs_to_update = Professor.objects.filter(id__in=id_set)

for prof in profs_to_update:
    prof.first_name = next(first_name for id, first_name in first_name_updates if id == prof.id)

Professor.objects.bulk_update(profs_to_update, ['first_name'])
```

Comment: Thanks for you advice, but now i have exception(MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one Professor).

Comment: You should be using filter not get, as per my answer

Comment: I did it by have this exception('QuerySet' object has no attribute 'pk')

Comment: which line is throwing that error

Comment: Python39\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py:493

Comment: I need to know which line in my answer that line corresponds to.

Comment: Your code work right but i have strange internal exception about this QuerySet